# Select and pluck in rails hitting same SQL query but with different result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am hitting the following query from my rails console :

```
Listing.joins(:colors, :sizes, :product, :orders).pluck('colors.id', 'sizes.id', 'products.id', 'orders.id')
   (4.5ms)  SELECT colors.id, sizes.id, products.id, orders.id FROM "listings" INNER JOIN "colors" ON "colors"."listing_id" = "listings"."id" INNER JOIN "sizes" ON "sizes"."listing_id" = "listings"."id" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "listings"."product_id" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."listing_id" = "listings"."id"
```

and

```
Listing.joins(:colors, :sizes, :product, :orders).select('colors.id', 'sizes.id', 'products.id', 'orders.id')
  Listing Load (4.6ms)  SELECT colors.id, sizes.id, products.id, orders.id FROM "listings" INNER JOIN "colors" ON "colors"."listing_id" = "listings"."id" INNER JOIN "sizes" ON "sizes"."listing_id" = "listings"."id" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "listings"."product_id" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."listing_id" = "listings"."id"
```

and got the following results respectively :

```
[[2, 3, 1, 1], [2, 3, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1, 2], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 2], [3, 3, 1, 1], [3, 3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1, 2], [3, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 2], [4, 3, 1, 1], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 2, 1, 1], [4, 2, 1, 2], [4, 1, 1, 1], [4, 1, 1, 2]]
```

and

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Listing id: 1>, #<Listing id: 2>, #<Listing id: 1>, #<Listing id: 2>, #<Listing id: 1>, #<Listing id: 2>, #<Listing id: 1>, #<Listing id: 2>, #<Listing id: 1>, #<Listing id: 2>, ...]>
```

Please help this is quiet confusing for me.

Comment: Pluck returns an array, select returns the object, in this case some Listings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused with the format of result provided by `pluck` and `select`.  `pluck` return result in simple Array where as `select` return array of Active Record Relations. That is why you getting same result as different format.

Hope it will clear your doubt.

Output for `pluck`:

```
[[2, 3, 1, 1], [2, 3, 1, 2]..]
```

Output for `select`:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation[#<Listing id: 1>, #<Listing id: 2>..]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing the use of pluck and select.

select specify which of the fields you want in your result set. But it returns the matching result set as Array of ActiveRecord Objects.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Listing id: 1>, #<Listing id: 2>, ...
```

Whereas the pluck does the same thing, i.e. it runs the select first with specified attributes, but instead of building ActiveRecord models it only plucks out those attributes values from result set and put them in a simple Array. Therefore you can only see the resulting Array of values instead of Array of Objects:

```
[[2, 3, 1, 1], [2, 3, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1, 2],...
```

Comment: While the result is the same, pluck doesn't ever create Active Record objects (indeed, that's half the point of it)